# Android: AppWidgetProvider cant change the updating interval time

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

In My application I have to use HomeScreenWidget. And every 2minutes It should update its content. So I tried the following steps

i) create AppWidgetProvider class

```
public class MainWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Log.i("onUpdate","called");
             this.context=context;
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);
                remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button,getServerData(context));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
    }

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("onreceive","called");
        this.context=context;
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MainWidget.class);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_tv1,aaa);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_tv2,bbb);
        manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
```

II) create widget_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout" 
  android:minHeight="72dp" 
  android:minWidth="294dp" 
  android:updatePeriodMillis="120000">

</appwidget-provider>
```

iii) Add widget class in Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".MainWidget" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>
```

My Widget is updating for every 30 minutes. I want to update the widget every 2 minutes..
Please provide me the best way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When specifying the update frequency in the `widget_info.xml`, the smallest update interval is 30 min (this is to conserve battery life). If you need a higher frequency of updates you should use the `AlarmManager` in conjunction with a `Service`.

Here's a tutorial that seem to use the AlarmManager: http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/04/simple-complete-app-widget-part-1.html